# Unable to set Expiry Time of File Object on AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0, aws-sdk-java

I am setting an expiry time of 30 minutes while uploading a FileInputStream to S3 bucket using AWS SDK , but the file was not deleted after 30 minutes . I even tried the next day at 12:00AM thinking maybe the queue is refreshed at night but still the file was accessible via the url . I even tried in incognito mode to ensure that no cache was being returned .I cannot make changes to the bucket configurations and no lifecycle has been defined for expiry on bucket .What is the minimum time that I can set for expiry and why is 30 minutes not working .

```
    ObjectMetadata data = new ObjectMetadata();
    data.setCacheControl("no-cache");
    data.setExpirationTime(Date.from(Instant.now().plus(30, ChronoUnit.MINUTES)));
PutObjectRequest r = new PutObjectRequest(bucket, file, fileInputStream,
                        data);
awsSdkClient.putObject(r);
```

Answer (score 2):

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectMetadata.html#setExpirationTime-java.util.Date-:

> For internal use only. This will *not* set the object's expiration time, and is only used to set the value in the object after receiving the value in a response from S3.

To add on this, it's not supported to set object expiration time manually. Object expiration is only available in lifecycle rules.

Comment: And how do we set lifecycle rules for expiry on some files in S3 bucket ?

Comment: You can checkout this help doc for details. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html